# Can linear classifiers be used at each node of a decision tree instead of the lines parallel to any one of the axes?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, linear-regression, decision-trees, ai

I am relatively new to AI/ML. I came across this question while reading some content on ML. Would be of great help if anyone can answer this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a decision in a node of a decision tree be based on comparison between 2 columns of the dataset?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60848/can-a-decision-in-a-node-of-a-decision-tree-be-based-on-comparison-between-2-col)

Comment: @BenReiniger Thanks for the comment but I dont think that answers my question. What I want to know is can Linear Classifiers be used to build a decision tree?